# Debian 9 switch from gnome to KDE fails to show windows

Tags: debian, kde5

I just switched from GNOME to KDE5 (with its default display manager) on Debian 9 by issuing:

```
apt-get install kde-full
apt-get purge gnome*
```

Now no windows are shown. I can launch the application menu but as programs open no window is shown.

What went wrong?

Comment: Though I don't know *why*, that's the window manager not starting. If you can start applications, you can try to start a console and run `kwin` manually. See if it works, and if it doesn't look at the errors.

Comment: I can start applications but i cannot see the windows... is there any shortcut to open a "run a command" windows in which i can easily type without seeing?

Comment: If `krunner` is launched,  `Alt+F2` opens a small box from where one can run commands, starts applications, find windows or trigger events. But it's odd, you mean you see nothing at all or you don't see window borders?

Comment: I don't see anything except the applications if i hover with the mouse on the application bar and the application launcher. So I can type in a terminal and kind of see the output.

Comment: I tried to start kwin from command line (ctrl+alt+F2 in login screen) but I get the following error: "win: FATAL ERROR while trying to open display"

Comment: If you run it from another terminal (through ctrl-alt-Fx switching), you need to give it the display explicitly: `DISPLAY=:0 kwin`

Comment: Keeps hunging... It's impossible to do it while the desktop is started.